# Drupal 7 to trigger whenver Menu is updated/changed?

Tags: events, drupal, menu, triggers, hook

In Drupal 7, i need to make some processes with `Menu` whenever it is changed. (Saved/ Updated/ Deleted)
How can i get it? Can someone pls tell me which `hook` or place should i trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think you probably want to know when a menu link gets changed, not an entire menu.  But just in case here are hooks for both...

Here are the hooks for menu modifications:

- [`hook_menu_insert`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!menu!menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_insert/7)
- [`hook_menu_update`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!menu!menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_update/7)
- [`hook_menu_delete`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!menu!menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_delete/7)

Here are the hooks for menu link modification:

- [`hook_menu_link_insert`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_insert/7)
- [`hook_menu_link_update`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_update/7)
- [`hook_menu_link_delete`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_delete/7)